# Preventing Page Load Before an Ajax Call Has Been Made

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

We're integrating with a single sign-on interface which provides a very nice remote JavaScript call to retrieve user information.  The library we reference via a remote URL even changes the state of the login/logout links and provides a bit of user data (their name and whatnot) when they have already authenticated.  The resource returns a Json object which we parse, and then update the session state within our app to maintain their user information.

Our issue is that ASP.NET serves the HTML and completes it's Page Load event(web forms) before the JavaScript object has been called and completed, and more importantly before the data is returned and the Ajax call is made to the server to update session.  The result is an on-page "flash" caused by JavaScript (it starts off as logged out and then switches to logged in once the script has finished) and pages that load in an incorrect state causing us to redirect the user needlessly.

Has anyone every played with preventing the page from loading prior to that remote script completing?  I know we can hide the body content until the script has finished, which will eliminate the flashing (and create an annoying wait for our users), but that won't eliminate our latent session issue.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

BD

Comment: can you convert the ajax call to jsonp? if so, then you can make the call as a <script> tag, which should delay the load event without the horror of "sync ajax".

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but you can wait for your javascript to execute after the page is loaded with `<body onload="jsCode()">`

Comment: Orry, let me see if this helps:  1) Anonymous user hits landing page, 2) ASP.NET page served by the server which writes out the HTML/JavaScript in the response, 3) JavaScript events fire and Json object is returned from the remote server, 4) Ajax call sends the returned data to the server, 5) session is updated on the server properly, but the page that was already loaded is now out of state because it loaded as if the user was anonymous even though the JavaScript found a cookie and logged them in.

Comment: Doesn't that script give you access to a completion callback? That will solve a lot of problems.. if it doesn't does it add any classes to the html or body tags? And does it modify the classes on your login buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the third party script  modifies classes on the elements in question or on the body or html tags.

This would allow you to hide the buttons  by default and use the added class(es) to include css rules that then display them

HTML

```
<!-- BEFORE -->
<button id="login-btn">Login</button>
<!-- AFTER-->
<button id="login-btn" class="loginScriptButtonClass">Login</button>
```

OR

```
<!-- BEFORE -->
<body>
<!-- AFTER-->
<body class="loginScriptBodyClass">
```

CSS

```css
#login {visibility:hidden}

#login.loginScriptButtonClass {visibility:visible}
.loginScriptBodyClass #login {visibility:visible}
```

If this isn't the case that it modifies classes it may also provide you a completion callback hook where you can toggle classes yourself

Comment: Yup, per your earlier comment we have access to a completion callback.  When that fires we're updating the server with the session information.  Our entire problem stems from the fact that the code executes on the remote server and there is a lag, sometimes as much as a few seconds between when the script starts and stops.  I'd hate to force the user to watch a blank page as the screen loads, but the alternative is this "jumping" behavior since the menu starts with "Login" and then updates to "Welcome [Your Name Here] | Log Out" a few seconds later.

Comment: And that lag is also the reason session gets wonky, because the past loads with an empty session and then session is properly updated a few seconds later, albeit after the page has already been built via the response.  I'm beginning to think that we might need to force a refresh when the completion callback indicates a successful login, but that will cause a pause in the page load and then a redirect, which is even more annoying to the user.

Comment: so you do as I suggested...load the page ( users needs speed ) and hide the login related elements until the request is completed and script does it's modifications. Session data can be updated in your ajax request

Comment: I am used to building single page javascript apps with lots of internal client side routing (full client side MVC) and authentication. I see no reason whatsoever you would need to do a full page reload

Comment: charlietfl, yes, you are correct, if we had the luxury of rebuilding this version we could implement your concept.  However, we need to retrofit a solution into an existing web forms app and simply don't have the budget to make such an overhaul.  Good solution though.

Comment: I think you are over complicating it... this is a really simple fix that can be done in minutes...not hours ...or days. i would hate to think that some simple css selectors can't be found in your html in about a minute where your button/message is shown and testing the css needed can be done live right in the browser dev tools